# Extract first part of a string in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a way to extract usernames from a link, it'll be the subdomain at the start.

Users of the application will have a choice, enter a username or a link to the profile

```
public static string GetUsernameFromLink(string link)
{
    if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(link, UriKind.Absolute))
    {
        // TODO: Extract
    }

    return link;
}
```

Either way, if they do a link it'll just be `username.website.com`. So lets say I enter `https://adam.hello.com` I need to extract `adam`

Comment: The question looks like a dupe to me. Maybe a `Regex` + `Substring` solution? Or else a `Regex` + `Split` solution? A single Google search gives plenty of results..

Comment: Is the domain always the same? I.e “hello.com”?

Comment: Yes @maccettura

Answer (score 6):

```
public static string GetUsernameFromLink(string link)
{
  if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(link, UriKind.Absolute))
  {
    // TODO: Extract
    Uri baseUri = new Uri(link);
    var un = baseUri.Host.Split('.').First();
  }

  return link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pure regex and will match urls with http, https, or without.

```
public static string GetUrlPart(string url)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:(?:http(s)?:\/\/)|^)(\w+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Match match = regex.Match(url);
    return match.Success ? match.Groups[2].Value : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: yes it does. Uri uri = new UriBuilder(someUrlString).Uri;  it defaults to a scheme if not present in the source string url, so it’s perfectly fine to parse out from there whatever piece you need.

Comment: BobK is nearly there so I upvoted theirs. Plus I’m on mobile and it’s a pain cause the app is trash.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = "https://www.google.com"; // Sample input
            Regex pattern = new Regex(@"[a-z]+(\.[a-z]+)+"); // Regular expression to match the domain
            Match match = pattern.Match(text); // Finds matches
            var domains = match.Value.Split('.'); // Get the match value and split it into an array.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(":", domains)); // Sample output
        }
    }
}
```

What happens here that, you declare a `Regex` instance, that captures the part of the URL string, that matches the typical pattern of a domain name, i.e.

```
[any number of a-z Characters ] [ followed by any number of instances of a group of characters, that starts with DOT and followed by any number of a-z Characters]
```

After capturing that, I split it into a `string[]` which, the 0th index contains what I want exactly.

The best thing about this approach is that it implicitly validates the input string. However in certain cases, `Regex` might introduce performance hits, which in your case is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
 var regex = new Regex(@"\/\/(.+?)\.");
 Match match = regex .Match(@"https://adam.hello.com");
 if(match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```

this code will write "adam"